# Reducir el ancho de Gtk.Cellrender en python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk

Estoy creando una columna angosta en **Gtk.TreeView**, pero al momento de editar  el Entry se expande.
He tratado con algunas propiedades como:

- cell.set_property('width', 50)
- cell.set_property('max_width_chars', 2)

pero no ha funcionado...

(Esta pregunta es similar a esta publicacion):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043082/reduce-size-of-edit-box-in-cellrenderertext-in-gtk-python

Básicamente la respuesta es ampliar el window/dialog/columna, pero quiero **dejarle ese tamaño a la columna "Edad"**

**Alguna idea si es posible?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es este:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class CellRendererTextWindow(Gtk.Window):

def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="CellRendererText Example")

    self.set_default_size(240, 200)

    self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
    self.liststore.append(["25", "David Gomez"])
    self.liststore.append(["30", "Vannesa Velazquez"])
    self.liststore.append(["26", "Juan Perez"])

    treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

    renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    renderer_text.set_property("editable", True)
    column_edad = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Edad", renderer_text, text=0)
    column_edad.set_min_width(1)
    column_edad.set_fixed_width(1)
    column_edad.set_sizing(Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing.FIXED)
    column_edad.set_resizable(False)
    column_edad.set_expand(False)

    # CAMBIOS QUE NO ME FUNCIONAN

    renderer_text.set_property('width', 80)
    renderer_text.set_fixed_size(80, 30)
    renderer_text.set_property('max_width_chars', 5)
    # column_edad.set_fixed_width(Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing.GROW_ONLY)
    # column_edad.set_expand(True)

    treeview.append_column(column_edad)

    renderer_editabletext = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    renderer_editabletext.set_property("editable", True)

    column_text2 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Nombre", renderer_editabletext, text=1)
    treeview.append_column(column_text2)

    renderer_editabletext.connect("edited", self.text_edited)

    self.add(treeview)

def text_edited(self, widget, path, text):

    self.liststore[path][1] = text

def on_toggle(self, cell, path):
    print "Toggled"

win = CellRendererTextWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Hola restifler, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Sería buena idea que agregaras el código o al menos un [mcve] para reproducir el problema, facilitas mucho la tarea de quién pueda responder y las respuestas siempre estarán más orientadas a tu implementación concreta.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla muchas gracias por la aclaracion y bienvenida.